# Convert "DOM Waiter" to namespacing listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, namespaces, listener

So I have a design framework installed over a SharePoint web site that I used to insert a list of files dynamically, the user does not have to do anything or click any buttons for the list to load. However, the dates in the results do not get formatted.

In the mean time, I came up with the following solution with the help of another user that checks for the DOMs until they are loaded and then performs the action of re-formatting the date values with MomentJS:

```
var timeout = null;
function waitForDom () {
  console.log("Checking DOM...");
  // check for the elements you expect to exist
  if ($(".shortpoint-listitem-subtitle").length) {
    $(".shortpoint-tab-title").click(function() {waitForDom();});
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    formatDates();
  }
  else {
    // adjust timeout time to whatever feels appropriate to you
    timeout = setTimeout(waitForDom, 500);
  }
}

waitForDom();

function formatDates() {
  $('.shortpoint-listitem-subtitle, .shortpoint-listitem-description').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var value=currentElement.text();
    var dateParseRegex = /\d\d\d\d[-]\d\d[-]\d\d[T]\d\d[:]\d\d:\d\d[.]\d{7}[Z]/g;
    var formattedDate = value.replace(dateParseRegex, function (match) {
      return moment(match).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    });
    currentElement.text(formattedDate);  
  });
}

setTimeout(function () {
  var content = '';
  $(".content").append(content);
}, 2300);
```

It works but it's not super performant. I reached out to the company and asked how I could hook into something more synchronous, their suggestion was to "listen to jQuery event like `shortpoint-init[ShortPoint Name]`". So for my case the event would be `shortpoint-initfiles-list`.

However after reviewing the jQuery event examples I'm not readily aware of how to set it up so that jQuery "listens" for these "events" to take place on the document / page so that it runs the code in a fashion that's more fluid than waiting for the DOMs. Most of the events seem to be responsive, that is, they wait for a user's input such as a click.

I think I'm looking for `namespacing events` but still not how to go about re-working this code into that.

The reason I do not put this code in a `document ready` or `document load` and other similar code is that the data is loaded asychronously, therefore the data/DOMs are not present even if the document/body is ready.

This should not be attached to any kind of clicking event/action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for namespaced events. You just want to hook the event on `document`:

```
$(document).on("shortpoint-initfiles-list", function(e) {
    // Here, `e.target` will be the element the event was fired on
});
```

I'm assuming these events bubble. I tried to look that up on [their knowledgebase](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/home), but there doesn't appear to be anything silly like an API reference (or they do a good job of hiding it).

Comment: So I just throw my formatDates code into the body of that function?

Comment: @ChristopherBruce: Assuming there's just the one list, yes. Otherwise you'd need to use `e.target` to figure out which list the event came from, I'm guessing.

Comment: Okay cool that works. I do have another interesting issue here, the other tabs don't have any data in them until you click them, at which point, the content in the div changes. However, the dates don't get formatted but if I click another element somewhere on the page, the date formatting gets updated. Is there a good solution for this? I realize the setup for this content is pretty janky. I can update my question for further clarification if needed.

Comment: No idea, you may need to open a ticket with the company asking for details on these events, when and how they're raised, etc.

Comment: Ah I think I was using the wrong event handler and also had my attempt in the wrong place in code, I ended up using this after your code and everything works great now. $(document).on("click", ".shortpoint-tab-title", function () {
  formatDates();
}); Thanks again.